# OneLogin/phpsaml in symfony2

Tags: onelogin

I need to let my users connect to another web App through SSO , but the other app uses Saml as its standard protocol for SSO ,  I found `Onelogin/phpSaml` which a lot of people seems to use but i didn't quite understand it . 
my situation is as follows : in this case i am the Service Provider and his App is the IdP , whant i want to know is how to use it under Syomfony.
where to save SP data and IDP data ? where do i put the data to be auth with (foreach user there is different data to be sent ) .
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building your own integration of php-saml at symfony you should review this package:
https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle

It already take care of php-saml settings, sso on app, just-in-time provisioning,..